# ec2 LAMP instance issue

Tags: apache, amazon-ec2

I have a micro instance on `AWS` that shows that it is running fine on Amazons dashboard
However when i log into the instance with `SSH` and try to start or stop apache 
`sudo service httpd stop`
`sudo service httpd start`
I get `[FAILED]`

`sudo apachectl start`
doesnt return anything

`sudo apachectl restart` gives me `httpd not running, trying to start`

What am i missing?  it seems to be doing this out of the blue
is there any `command line` i can test to see where the issue is coming from?

Comment: You have an error in your `httpd.conf` file. Also, this belongs in ServerFault

Comment: Try to `/etc/init.d/httpd start`. After that you can check if 80 port is open: `netstat -tulpn | grep :80`

Comment: `sudo su` first - you have to be root!

Comment: @RomanNewaza `Starting httpd: [FAILED]`

Comment: Okay, now check log for Apache2 errors

Comment: @RomanNewaza where do i find that? inside `/var/log` there are a lot of files

Comment: `grep -i apache /var/log/syslog`

Comment: also: `grep -i apache /var/log/messages`

Comment: sudo grep -i apache /var/log/syslog = `grep: /var/log/syslog: No such file or directory`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15246/discussion-between-t-q-and-roman-newaza)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you changed anything in the configuration file?

> /etc/init.d/httpd configtest

Is there something else listening on port 80?

> fuser -n tcp 80

Comment: the httpd file hasent changed, `fuser -n tcp 80` nothing happens

Comment: actually it was a file that appends httpd.conf for virtual domains.  a `ssl` cert was not configured properly

Comment: This is three years late, but how did you end up fixing that? I am having same issue, and trying to follow this tutorial: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/SSL-on-an-instance.html . The last part of step 2 messed me up